# How can I import java existing project in Eclipse before it's start first time?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want that when i start eclipse first time by default my eclipse import some project in its workspace.

Means if any user start eclipse first time, there should be some project in workspack or project explorer.

How can i implement this?

Comment: Who is *any user*? Any user on your computer, what operating system, etc? Any user on some network, in some domain?

Comment: we are executing exe file that runs some batch files and copy eclipse with workspace to the users m/c. when user started eclipse there should pre-imported project in explorer.

Comment: I'd suggest you should include the startup projects in the default workspace, copied by your batch files. Wouldn't you?